# Resize canvas maintaining proportions of content, avoid stretching

Tags: canvas, resize, babylonjs, stretching

I'm creating a canvas element to place some Babylon content. I want that canvas to be full width and full height responsive. For that I used this JS:

```js
$( window ).resize( function () {
  $('#canvas').css({
     "height": window.innerHeight,
     "width": window.innerWidth
  });
});
```

That works fine resizing the content, but the content is streatching itself when I resize the window.

How can I avoid that stretching?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to avoid using CSS to style a canvas. That changes the DOM element but the drawing pixels are unchanged resulting in distortions. Use JS to  set properties `canvas.width = innerWidth` and height. Unrelated, but it's a good idea  to debounce the resize event firing as well after you fix the stretching problem.

Comment: Thanks, that works!